# How do I use array_filter() to group posts by their categories?

Tags: php, wordpress, grouping, posts, array-filter

I have a custom post type called ***cpt-magazines***, and a custom taxonomy called ***ctax-publication-year***. In my template-file, I want to use array_filter() to group the posts by their category (all posts only have one category assigned to them), get some meta data from Advanced Custom Fields, and output the posts in the order of their titles.

End result goal:

#### Category "1935"

**Magazine #1, 1935**
*<Magazine #1 meta data>*

**Magazine #2, 1935**
*<Magazine #2 meta data>*

#### Category "1936"

**Magazine #1, 1936**
*<Magazine #1 meta data>*

**Magazine #2, 1936**
*<Magazine #2 meta data>*

... and so on.

Currently, this is as far as I have gotten with my code (note that $iteration is only there to limit the output while I'm figuring out the code):

```
<section class="section-magazines has-padding">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
            
      <?php
      // Get categories
      $getTerms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy'    => 'ctax-publication-year',
        'orderby'     => 'title',
        'order'       => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty'  => false
      ) );

      // Query arguments
      $queryArgs = array(
        'post_type'        => 'cpt-magazines',
        'posts_per_page'   => '-1',
      );

      $postsQuery = new WP_Query( $queryArgs );
      $postsArray = $postsQuery->posts;
      ?>
            
      <div class="col-12">
        <?php
        $iteration = 1;
        
        foreach ( $getTerms as $term ) {
        
          // Limit to 2 categories while testing
          if ( $iteration > 2 ) {
            break;
          }
          
          echo "<h2>". $term->name ."</h2>";
        
          $postsInCategory = array_filter( $postsArray, function($post) {
            return $post->term_id == $term->term_id;
          } );
        
          var_dump($postsInCategory);
        
          $iteration++;
        }
        ?>
      </div>
            
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

So far I've been able to print out all of the categories names inside the H2 tags, so I feel like I've got that part down. What I am struggling with figuring out right now is how to filter through the posts that have the category of each category-loop, and how to get the meta data from each of those post.
My code right now outputs an array of 251 items (which is the total amount of posts of the custom post type) along with some data for each of them, and it looks like this (I cut it off very short, because it's a very long array, of course):

```
array(251) { 
  [0]=> object(WP_Post)#8876 (24) { 
    ["ID"]=> int(9250) 
    ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2020-08-07 12:04:14" 
    ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2020-08-07 10:04:14" 
    ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["post_title"]=> string(14) "Tegel #1, 1987" 
    ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" 
    ["comment_status"]=> string(6) "closed" 
    ["ping_status"]=> string(6) "closed" 
    ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["post_name"]=> string(12) "tegel-1-1987" 
    ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2020-08-07 12:04:14" 
    ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2020-08-07 10:04:14" 
    ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["post_parent"]=> int(0) 
    ["guid"]=> string(52) "http://spef:8888/?post_type=cpt-magazines&p=9250" 
    ["menu_order"]=> int(0) 
    ["post_type"]=> string(13) "cpt-magazines" 
    ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" 
    ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" 
}
```

I think that I vaguely understand how the array_filter() function works, but I don't quite know how to retrieve / use data inside it.

Thank you in advance for any assistance!